# SSO authentication angular application with service gateway call

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ldap, single-sign-on, websecurity

We have an application which is built using Angular. And the application trigger backend REST api to display data.

The issue was,

The application use LDAP SSO authentication to validate user (It is an internal application within company so no outside users)

The steps are,

1. If user launch the site, It will redirect to WebSec login where user provides username and password for authentication (Implicit flow).
2. Once the successful authentication, we will JWT access token from WebSec which will be stored in session storage and that will be used as "Bearer" token for backend services.
3. The backend service has its WebSec certificate to validate this JWT token at their side if not it will respond with Authentication error.

For Front end - We are using Angular
For back end - We are Java, Sprint boot.

Questions are,

1. Is this right way for User authentication?
2. If so, how safe is the Implicit flow. Ref: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ - Everyone is recommending Explicit flow (Server side call). Our UI app is maintained in different server and Backend services are maintained different server.

I would appreciate if anyone provide solution on this.

Comment: Does your LDAP SSO supports explicit flow?

Comment: Are you in a position to make any changes to your LDAP SSO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way i've saw until now is the following (I have also running a MS Single-Sign-On Server as you described), but i would recommend it doing it like Discord do it:

1. Your Frontend Redirects to the SSO with a `redirect_link` and a `application_id` and claims to request
2. Your SSO redirects to the `redirect_link` if Authentication is successful and the `application_id` is known, but with a random created `code=$myCode`, could be a JWT or whatever long string
3. Your Frontend sends this Code to your backend, then your backend ask the SSO server if this is a valid `code` and requests a real authentication bearer token.
4. If all fine your Frontend gets the real authentication token from *your API*

If this chain is all successful you can be pretty sure that everything is fine in your internal network. This is for company internal a good enough approach.

For external usage you can provide a secure key with step 1 and 2 that the sso have to provide back for the frontend which is generated from the frontend to be sure that this redirect comes from your SSO.

EDIT: some more details on encryption:

Your SSO encrypts the code maybe with HS512 which will be send to the client and later to the SSO again through the API. On this cycle if the SSO can decrypt and validate it and the API is a known/allowed communication partner you can say that all sides are trusted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with implicit flow is that the JWT token is present in the URL. The implicit flow can be implemented in your Front-end or Back-end, both are not recommended but doing it in Front-end has more vulnerabilities, which is what you are trying to do, if I understood your question correctly.

I would implement it the following way.

1. Your Front-end will redirect to WebSec login
2. On successful login, WebSec will redirect to your Back-end
3. Back-end retrieves the JWT token
4. Back-end creates a **one-time** token and redirects to your Front-end with that one-time token
5. Front-end retrieves the one-time token and **POST** the token to the Back-end to retrieve the JWT token

Comment: Thats a pretty bad way to let a API redirect to the frontend. I would never recommend this approach.

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull would like to know what is bad about this approach and what is the better way of doing it, can you throw some light?

Comment: I am not recommending implicit flow,clearly mentioned in my answer, but if you see the point #2 in the question, it seems that his SSO doesn't support explicit flow. So my answer was how better he can implement it if his SSO doesn't support explicit flow. If his SSO supports explicit flow I will definitely recommend that only and the user himself seems to know it based on the link he has shared.

Comment: Well true, but for only internal usage the implicit flow should also be good enough. When someone tries to hack from internal there are other security problems.